# How to stop Search Engines from indexing SharePoint Site

Tags: 2010, search, crawling

I have SharePoint 2010 Enterprise for Internet Sites. Some search results in Google & Bing are pointing to my intranet site URL which is intranet.mysite.com

I want to cloak my site totally from Search Engines.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a robots.txt to your root.

in this robots.txt you can put information about what pages may and may not be indexed. For more information check:

http://www.robotstxt.org/

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

edit:
waldek mastykarz has made a solution that automatically creates a robots.txt for you: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/generating-robots-txt-files-mavention-robots-txt/

PS: is your intranet anonymous accessible?

Comment: remember that SharePoint search itself also checks for robots.txt so you will either have to allow for SharePoint user agent or disallow specific web robots

Comment: @Bas What do you mean by root? Is it the Login page?

Comment: @Bas No it is not anonymous accessible!

Comment: @Saumil Then i think it's strange that your site gets indexed! That should not happen. It's smart to check if it's really not accessible by anonymous users!

Comment: @Anders Rask: that is a very good caveat! Good reminder, that is

Comment: @Bas I uploaded the files to root. But now it is asking me for SharePoint username & password when I click on the link i.e. http://intranet.mysite.com/robot.txt. So it means that file is still not accessible to Crawlers. Can you please let me know how to un-protect the robots.txt file so that it is publicly visible? Thx!